# Performance counter for "Largest free region"?

Tags: .net, windows, performance, memory, memory-management

I'm debugging an out-of-memory exception.  When I get the exception, the "virtual bytes" performance counter indicates plenty of addressable space.  The problem, however, is that the addressable space is badly fragmented, and the "Largest free region" (returned from !address in WinDbg) is too small.

To measure the memory fragmentation, I would like to monitor the "Largest free region" in perfmon.  Is there a performance counter that gives me this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there's a single performance counter for this piece of information, but it can be deduced by using the `VirtualQueryEx` Win32 function.

You can call it on the minimum valid virtual address (which can be obtained from `GetSystemInfo`), you can then use the size of the returned page range to determine the base address of the next page range for which to call `VirtualQueryEx`.

By walking through the address space with repeated calls to `VirtualQueryEx` like this you can determine the largest page range of type MEM_FREE and what its base address is.

This is the technique that I used for my 'Address Space Monitor' program.

Answer (score 1):

From http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/06/30/perfmon-your-debugging-buddy/ :

Virtual Address Space Fragmentation Indicators:

- Number of total reserved Bytes significantly larger than # total committed Bytes
- Number of Pinned Objects increasing
- Number of GC handles increasing
- Number of bytes in all heaps always increasing.

Comment: These are some good indicators, but the worst offenders are actually outside of .NET inside C dlls that memory map files.  These indicators assume that the problem is visible form .NET, but unfortunatelly it is not in my case.

Comment: If you could look at reserved bytes vs. committed bytes, that would give you a better idea. I don't see a counter like that though.

MSN

Answer (score 0):

Using the code I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716227/Csharp-How-to-Scan-a-Process-Memory), here's a code example of [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444589/322740):

```
public class MemoryAnalyzer {
    public long GetLargestFreeRegionSize() {
        // getting minimum & maximum address
        SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
        GetSystemInfo(out sysInfo);

        var procMinAddress = sysInfo.minimumApplicationAddress;
        var procMaxAddress = sysInfo.maximumApplicationAddress;

        // saving the values as long ints so I won't have to do a lot of casts later
        var procMinAddressL = (long)procMinAddress;
        var procMaxAddressL = (long)procMaxAddress;

        // current process
        var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        // opening the process with desired access level
        var processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);

        long maxFreeRegionSize = 0;

        while (procMinAddressL < procMaxAddressL) {
            const int memBasicInfoSize = 28; //sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)
            MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memBasicInfo;
            VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, procMinAddress, out memBasicInfo, memBasicInfoSize);

            if (memBasicInfo.State == MEM_FREE) {
                maxFreeRegionSize = Math.Max(maxFreeRegionSize, memBasicInfo.RegionSize);
            }

            // move to the next memory chunk
            procMinAddressL += memBasicInfo.RegionSize;
            procMinAddress = new IntPtr(procMinAddressL);
        }

        return maxFreeRegionSize;
    }

    #region Win32
    // REQUIRED CONSTS
    const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
    const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;
    const int MEM_FREE = 0x10000;

    // REQUIRED METHODS
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern void GetSystemInfo(out SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);

    // REQUIRED STRUCTS
    public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION {
        public int BaseAddress;
        public int AllocationBase;
        public int AllocationProtect;
        public int RegionSize;
        public int State;
        public int Protect;
        public int lType;
    }

    public struct SYSTEM_INFO {
        public ushort processorArchitecture;
        ushort reserved;
        public uint pageSize;
        public IntPtr minimumApplicationAddress;
        public IntPtr maximumApplicationAddress;
        public IntPtr activeProcessorMask;
        public uint numberOfProcessors;
        public uint processorType;
        public uint allocationGranularity;
        public ushort processorLevel;
        public ushort processorRevision;
    }
    #endregion
}
```